# Tuple returned by function is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nonetype

I have written a function that takes a value and a list. The function looks between which 2 values of the list the value is positioned; and returns a tuple with the upper and lower positions.

If I call my function with a single value I can subscript the resulting tuple. However, if I put my function in a for loop which calls it many times, it gives me the following error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

I am new to Python. I will appreciate any help. Maybe it can be coded in a more efficient way.

Notes: yearFractions is a NumPy array containing floating numbers in its elements.

CODE:

```py
import numpy as np

yearFractions = np.array([0.22777778, 0.47777778, 0.73333333, 0.98888889, 1.24166667, 1.49166667, 1.74722222])

vertices = {0.25 : 0,
            0.5 : 0,
            1 : 0,
            2 : 0,
            3 : 0,
            4 : 0,
            5 : 0,
            10 : 0,
            15 : 0,
            20 : 0,
            30 : 0
}

#My function
def findPosition(value, valuesList):
    lastIndex = len(valuesList) -1 
    for i in range(len(valuesList)):
        if value >= valuesList[i] and value < valuesList[i+1]:
            return i, i+1
        elif value > valuesList[lastIndex]:
            return lastIndex-1, lastIndex

#Calling my function in a for loop
for i in yearFractions:
    pos = findPosition(i, list(vertices.keys()))
    print(pos[0])
```

Comment: The error is indicating that `None` is being returned; not a tuple. If you get through the whole loop without either of those conditions being true, nothing is returned. You'll need to handle that case.

Comment: BTW, `valuesList[i+1]` will get an error when you get to the last iteration because it's outside the list.

Comment: I think your loop looks odd - it will ONLY ever look at the first element, and return 1,i+1, or lastIndex-1, lastIndex - regardless of the contents of the rest of the valuesList. But you should always get something returned from it.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 That would be true if `elif` were `else:`. But if neither condition is true the loop continues to the nest element.

Comment: @Barmar - True - but it seems odd every time round the loop to compare `value` to a value that isn't changing.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 thanks for your comment. I wrote the for loop just for ilustration. Actually what I need is asigning pos[0] to one variable, and pos[1] to another variable. However, it does not alow me to subscript the resulting tupple.  If I print pos whith out subscripting it works well for all the values in yearFractions.

Comment: @billy - the reason you can't is because you aren't getting a tuple - you are getting None. And you get the None because you fall out of the Loop, and you fall out of the loop because the value 0.22277788 from your array is smaller then all of your vertices, and you don't handle that case.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 thank you very much, it seems to be the problem. I will need to adjust my code to consider values between 0 and 0.25. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your function :

```
def findPosition(value, valuesList):
    lastIndex = len(valuesList) -1 
    for i in range(len(valuesList)):
        if value >= valuesList[i] and value < valuesList[i+1]:
            return i, i+1
        elif value > valuesList[lastIndex]:
            return lastIndex-1, lastIndex
```

The elif section will be evaluated every time around the loop, which I don't think you want to do. Also your function entirely ignores what happens if one of your values is smaller than the smallest value in valuesList. And the first value in your numpy array is smaller then your smallest limit.

I don't know what you expect to return when you get a value that is too small, so it is impossible to say how to fix it.

Comment: The `elif` code should just be taken out of the loop, and be executed if the loop finishes.

Comment: But the question about what to do with a value that's too low still remains.

Comment: Barmar - agreed. But that alone doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I will not have negative values, but I do have values between 0 and 0.25, so I have to fix it.

Comment: Why the elif clause will be evaluated every time? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @billy - it is inside the for loop so when the `if` isn't true it will check the `elif`.
You actually want that `elif` outside the loop - probably in an `else` clause on the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the case where the value is less than all elements in the valuesList. The case where (assuming valuesList is sorted in ascending order):

```
value < valuesList[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a bit to run faster

```
def findPosition(value, valuesList):
    # if key list is not in ascending use "valuesList = valuesList.sort()"
    if value > valuesList[-1]:                             # -1 to access last element
      return len(valuesList), len(valuesList)            # given value greater then last value of list
    else:
      for idx, val in enumerate(valuesList):
        if val>value and idx <= len(valuesList) - 1:     # given value is less then the current value of the list and index
          break;                                         # break to stop the for loop when req value is reached
      return idx, idx+1
```